# CustomTkinter - Disabling tabs in Tabview (Notebook)

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

I'm looking for a way to disable specific tabs with the Tabview widget (resembling Notebook in Tkinter) for a custom module of it; "CustomTkinter" by Tom Schimansky if anyone is familiar with it. I am aware that this custom module doesn't carry over all the functionality of Tkinter but I was wondering if anyone else has had been here too.

State of a tab can be declared with Notebook:

```
self.notebook = ttk.Notebook(self)
self.tab1 = ttk.Frame(self.notebook)
self.notebook.add(self.tab1, text='Tab 1', state='disabled')
self.notebook.pack()
```

And later changed like so:
`self.notebook.tab(0, state='disabled')`

However this functionality is unsupported in CustomTkinter so I tried stimulating disabled tabs by tracking tab changes:
`self.notebook.bind("<<NotebookTabChanged>>", self.ignore_tab)` 
self.ingore_tab would redirect the user back to original tab somewhat like this:

```
def ignore_tab(self, event):
    selected_tab = self.notebook.index(self.notebook.select()) 
    if selected_tab == 1:
        self.notebook.select(0)
```

However it seems `"<<NotebookTabChanged>>"` was not implemented either (same with alternatives like `"<ButtonRelease-1>"` when used with Tabview)

Does anyone have any ideas about how I could make it work?

Comment: Couldn't you just use the tkinter notebook, and skip custom tkinter for that one widget? It's all tk in the long run.

Comment: @OneMadGypsy Yes that might actually work, thank you.